# Delayed_Job gives "unitilialized constant" while queueing a Custom Job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job

I'm trying to set up a custom job using the delayed_job gem with Rails 3.1.1. Whenever I queue a custom job I get a Name Error for my custom job.

Here's the code:

```
# POST /redemptions
def create
  @redemption = Redemption.new(params[:redemption])


  respond_to do |format|
    if @redemption.save
      @account = @redemption.coupon.merchant.account
      Delayed::Job.enqueue RedemptionJob.new(@account.id)
      format.json {render json: @redemption, status: :created, location: @redemption }
    else
      format.json {render json: @redemption.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

#  This code gives me the error "NameError (uninitialized constant RedemptionsController::RedemptionJob):
#  app/controllers/redemptions_controller.rb:9:in `block in create'
#  app/controllers/redemptions_controller.rb:6:in `create'"
```

I've tried giving the `RedemptionJob` a global namespace `::RedemptionJob.new(...)` but the NameError message still shows up (only without the `RedemptionsController`).

RedemptionJob.rb exists in /app/jobs/ and I've restarted the server to make sure it gets loaded. `rake jobs:work !` is running as well.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?